# Which is the best way to create an ECR repository using CDK?

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm using CDK for a while and I'm not sure yet which is the best way to launch a stack that create an ECR repository, building and sending a docker image to ECR.

My last try was something like that:

```js
    taskDefinition.addContainer("container", {
      image: new AssetImage('./', {
        repositoryName: "name"
      })
    });
```

But there is an issue on this approach, the `repositoryName` is deprecated at `AssetImage` class and it looks deprecated everywhere.

Can someone tells how can we launch this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 9):

The answer from Pedreiro shows the right way to build and upload an image. CDK will automatically create an ECR repository for you in that case.

I highly recommend to use the `aws-ecs-patterns` module to get stared with ECS on CDK. It provides already some common use cases where you can deploy an ECS service with very little code. The overview page is a good starting point: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ecs-patterns-readme.html

But in the unlikely case you wanted to just create an ECR repository using CDK you can do it like this:

```js
const repository = new ecr.Repository(this, 'Repository');
```

Check out the corresponding docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ecr-readme.html

Answer (score 6):

The code you are showing is not building an ECR and instead, deploying an ECS task definition.
If you are trying to build the docker image at deployment time, CDK has a handy funcionality to do both at the same time with assets:

```js
image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromAsset('./image') // build and upload an image directly from a Dockerfile in your source directory.
```

Otherwise, please check the Image options available in the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ecs-readme.html#images

Answer (score 2):

Notice there's an issue with

```
image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromAsset('./image')
```

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/2663
where you can not specify a tag, as a result in the ECS task it by default go for the latest, and the pull img will fail